# How to make a multi-user Flask application

Tags: python, flask

I need solution for multiple users service when one user login to their account and setup data from upload function to then start function to execute only for this user. In the same time if another user is logged in there account to have the same function to use. How can I do this?

```
@app.route('/upload', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['myfile']
        data_list.append(request.form['username'])        
        with open(f, 'r') as file:
            data_lst = [line.strip() for line in file]

        return render_template('index.html')
 

@app.route('/start', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def mainfunc():
    #Do something with the data_lst list
```

I need to know how each user can use app.py file  separate and not to affect the another user mainfunc(). I mean each user to upload file and use the mainfunc().

Comment: Please elaborate your question better and provide more details. If possible, present a piece of code for the problem.

Comment: In your current example there are a lot of open questions. In order to create a multi-user environment, I advise you to [flask_login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). 
Please also take a look at [this example](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/) to upload files.
As a good introduction to development with flask, I recommend [this 
tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world).

Comment: So I need to do first flask login and then each user can use the application without affection another user.Thank you for the tutorials

Comment: Flask login is an easy-to-use standard solution for creating a login option, limiting routes to logged-in users and identifying the currently logged-in user within a route. Starting from this point, you can use a user-specific folder to ensure that a user can only edit their files. Your requirements are currently difficult for me to assess. Feel free to leave me a comment if my approach isn't enough, you have something else in mind, or you need more information.